# Capturing Gestures over a UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview, ios4, gestures

I am trying to set up a simple iPad application that has a table view and when you select a row for that table it displays a (drilled down to) UIWebView displaying the selected web page (related to the row selected).

Once in the drilled-down-to view I want to capture EVERY touch and gesture (tap, swipe, pinch, etc) and do my own thing with them.  Yes, I know this will make navigating and interacting with the web page displayed impossible, that's the idea.

I have found and played around with the Stack Overflow question that was answered by this wepage: http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way/ and I can't get gestures to work with idea.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: have u tried using gesture recognizer ?? can you please post working code for the above mentioned way from webpage!! I am getting SIGBART error...

Comment: From same blog-comments section"Alan Moore said...
Jeff, thanks for your helpful reply. Unfortunately, it seems that this still doesn't work on iOS4. I ended up using the Gesture Recognizers and that does work on iPad and iOS4 so I'm happy!"(My intention is not to spam, I didn't find edit option)

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView already has a lot of gestureRecognizer attached to them. It might be a good idea to remove all those gesture recognizer before adding yours, as a testing unit.

If your gesture recognizer works, that means you could basically store the default recognizer in a private array and as soon as you want to give normal behavior to your webview again, you "reset" the UIWebView recognizer